# How to pass string input as integer arguments?

Tags: python, string, integer, arguments

I wanted to do the following simple calculation by passing values for the parameters `num1` and `num2` from `input()` methods.

I tried following code:

```
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

num1 = input('Enter number1: ')
num2 = input('Enter number2: ')

print(add(num1, num2))
```

But it is showing the following error when it is run (After input `num1` and `num2`):

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Can somebody please explain where did I go wrong and how to convert an input string to the integer type?

Comment: Just a comment on intentions: are you sure a function named `add` should perform multiplication?

Answer (score 6):

`input()` will returns a string, you have to convert the string to a `int` or `float`, you can test if the input is a valid number.

`isnumeric()` will return true if all chars in the string are numeric ones and the string is not empty.

Note: i renamed the function to `multiply` because this is not adding ...

```
def multiply(num1,num2):
    return num1*num2

inp1=input('Enter number1: ')
inp2=input('Enter number2: ')

if inp1.isnumeric() and inp2.isnumeric():
    num1 = int(inp1)
    num2 = int(inp2)
    print(multiply(num1,num2))
else:
    print("Atleast one input is not numeric")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the additional tip! It will be very useful!

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

num1 = int(input('Enter number1: '))
num2 = int(input('Enter number2: '))

print(add(num1, num2))
```

The [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function stores the input as a string and so what is happening in your code is that you are entering two integers but they are being stored as strings. You cannot multiply two strings. All you need to do is convert the input strings to integers by using the `[int()][2]` function. If you want to multiply floats, you can use the `[float()][3]` function in place of the `int()` function. You can also convert the strings to integers or floats once you have passed them into the function. Something like this:

```
def add(num1, num2):
    return int(num1) * int(num2)

num1 = input('Enter number1: ')
num2 = input('Enter number2: ')

print(add(num1, num2))
```

Answer (score 1):

`input` (in Python 3) returns a `str` which is seen as text and not a number. If you want to multiply (or add) numbers, you must first parse the strings as numbers.

Sometimes this will fail as well. If you're assuming the input is always going to be a valid number, you can convert a string using:

```py
float("3.1415926")
```

You can use this in your code with:

```py
def add(num1,num2):
    return num1*num2

num1=float(input('Enter number1: '))
num2=float(input('Enter number2: '))

print(add(num1,num2))
```

To avoid floating point errors, you can print/display the float using an f-string (added in Python 3.6).

```py
def add(num1,num2):
    return num1*num2

num1=float(input('Enter number1: '))
num2=float(input('Enter number2: '))

print(f"{add(num1,num2):.2f}")
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked! I have little doubt. When I changed the input type as float (randomly put values as num1=1.34 and num2=0.11), the result was, "1.4500000000000002". What is the reason for this value instead of just 1.45?

Comment: This is a classic computer science problem called [floating point error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point_error_mitigation). You can think about the number being added as "1.450...02" and choose to display the float using a limited number of decimal places. `print(f"{add(num1,num2):.2f})`. This assumes Python >= 3.6.

Answer (score -1):

```
def mul(num1,num2):
    return(num1*num2)

inp1 = input('Enter number1:')
inp2 = input('Enter number2:')

num1 = int(inp1)
num2 = int(inp2)

print(mul(num1,num2))
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation

Comment: In what way is that different from the other answers here?